# CSS file appears as rubbish

Tags: css, caching, encoding, cloud9

I've been using Cloud 9 (ace-editor) for a while, and recently we made an local server-cache solution that allow us to store local cachefiles of previewfiles from cloud9.

When I include a file directly from preview.c9, it works! But when I run the local cache version I end up with a file looking like this

```
‹������ÅXmoÛ6þî_Á¹Ü‘å·$ŽŠaÅú2Y»�Éö¥ÛJ¢mV/Ô(*MZô¿ïŽ/2¥ÈA‹í‡$6yw<Þ=÷Ü1Ï’•5Sdüçõ«`=~:z¶¥
64aäãˆû­àù]D&q“òD”“§°SË$"ÌOÂ0Í§©U,n›šIP¬TÓDa.V'ç'³³y˜¤e Y-™°:Lr2ÁV6¥
+)2æ 'ƒ&—¸’†xxhÏœ2¡~^-ÖëÓ“³ÅäÉ÷öàg~;y’U'¬ˆYš²4Üë®b“'Çß2<ïÅfãÅ§õ×¿±+J
z¢dÃ¾C`ê›m—GÀû¼Á¶A“Fú{Æ·;‘³š#Èôr­îr¶_ý4ŠEzw<ªŽGuEËãÝ×JÍ?€ä|]Ý¶ÚjËçòš\Ñ²ž“þP*|ótôi´›÷õWV¿ rËË J‰""Ëš…E_a±òt·ˆEž¢‰È…ŒÈ£Ùl†ÚÓX•Z?2e°1¯nI-rž¢ÈâùÉ
•Ìf iÊ›:" é‚Ñ¹áÞ¶STìV)K„¤Š‹ÃV2Ô®DÍÍŠd9ìÝèÕ”×UN]x™ó’q.’ŒüÀ‹JHEK¥5išòr‘Ss¼þÈFú*•‘r¶ô­Nä¢˜A±ZÛ»Bc¸y£»‚ç[F‹ÈxŒ_cšd[)š2
xA·oäÁRU}&*)ÊtÇ8^±
y!’!zU¿ÃS€¥æ8ï(É*F56Fñ#º&4`“ÿ÷<U»ˆ,t�:ž`âM(/QÕ„jn!…á|«�nLý4ŽsZŽÿéDVšƒVÈGt®µÚˆMþfñìTw]J®l%¢#¦ÄQµÙ@¹{.ÏážG!¬Ù›ÒF ñu’ÃéV¢ŠH�à÷£1û¿Y8Eê˜Ò"UCÔUÒÛ$§u
1C,½ Ý‡ã=qú?pÙ‰èØ†TCÔÅËáÂ1†p@• (¹²YÔµT¤ƒfxÈÓðF�øÓÍÐcººÛ�RIJë¢‡_4¥#ìûáGªØø•-��j²)K}}³³3t§Ÿ9Ÿ‹|ðï,Ò}”«
Çm`Ïh\Ìá{'Â¢Öº-¤¹-Ñ>ÅÛå=d}²üð2e·Pà÷£CøFÒÂðÛÏ–ßØ3©ð¨€Ö
Ž®`ˆåçÂƒÜÌaÍOškS³a¼\!²Ì¼ÐnÞ±èëáEgÚ«>›˜™`OKºÿb<ÔÛfH+PÖ–¿°Óú°¶¬‡·MÍt~Â
]¾v08 =â``ìöÙSëW[_~GC¼¶Éëwi0?]{øûõyðœ–
t»Yßo7_—7ô_
m‡àÁªuÖ¶×èº³¤[í´¿¶ýÀ¼¥n9U'¥Èô(DH>~RôÈçÓÝl¢hœú°³ÉiUÃ|ã>íÁÀä›è™˜h¨ý* 3nE%¼†P ÇH½GŸ½›8úµ³îË”«×¬l®¹ÂQüx%ÖÌÏ0p ùç;ZnÙËœpÞ5<¿"‚ï
Üršo€#rÅ2±jÑÐõRçó³­¼fy.
…<’£~e‹þ£wžõô*ãyÎ4×hO»î\JžeL1CFž)¿õvUzýutæ¦úwP+É+è­®\Óüˆ‰V4u-í0F;&„¯á‘ÉÊàùRnQiw2uá\µ—Õ”:Ü_˜¤kÉ²¬® päóÏ í«¥wÄEI«ÊØw;ÆÍßé–d¸ÙªïŸNÒºù[†C·‘ÓcÐÏÀÅ/í|î  n%­v¢¿JªŸvtªí%úQã§Äøx‘H¿gï†§LØû×=¹¸‰]±º»X|—,Æv=qü·LÆî¿A4†­«(Js5 ú‹l çžÕ*Jš>×uâBox’7Ï´®Ø%>D0µ:F5¼>N½Rï˜Äd+˜Šd@î…È,~O0¡9+ÓA«z«s›ÙnÈ¨Ñ­†Gúél¼„øýÊ{#¶-È¼´¸ÆÉaºL¡gù
1‡Îé¬§ ‘ó€BÊPâ]Â è°Òz‰­ÔwËé°
```

oT�P¨Ìú*X‡5ÎÙyï�Øâñ¢'ŽX–Çì-ú±Ä”^¯úÆìªœŸë\x‰0Ø;¨°ŽÏô`lþZvx²��

Any idea of whats cousing this?

PS: Sorry for poor english

Comment: yep, problem is charater encoding, unfortunately with no code provided no will be able to give you an answer. that's why you should always include code.

Comment: yeah, looks fine on my end. you'll have to dig up the code that is actually doing the caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an error in the encoding import.

I will return with the error / and fix as soon I get it firmly tested.